# How do I make this function occur after two $.getJSON functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

Originally, I had it with just `$(document).ready(update());` but that didn't work since the first `$.getJSON` was too slow. When I added the setTimeout, the first `$.getJSON` loaded but the second one didn't. Now, I understand WHY this is happening (because JSON is asynchronous), but I don't understand how I am supposed to fix it. I've been looking at `.then`, but every time I use it, it seems I either use it incorrectly or it doesn't change the situation.

```js
// Original Code

$.getJSON("workshops.json", function(data){
    workshopData = data;
});

$.getJSON("summers.json", function(data){
    summerData = data;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(update(), 0);
});
```

```
// Attempt at .then
function gatherData(){
    $.getJSON("workshops.json", function(data){
        workshopData = data;
    });

    $.getJSON("summers.json", function(data){
        summerData = data;
    });
};

gatherData().then(function(e){
    update();
    console.log("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) method here. The `$.when()` method accepts a list of deferred parameters such as the `jqXHR` request returned by your `$.getJSON` method (you can think of jqXHR as an object which wraps the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) interface). The `$.when()` will then run each deffered action concurrently and execute the `.done()` callback with resolved values as its arguments.

See example below:

```
function gatherData() {
  const jqxhr1 = $.getJSON("workshops.json");
  const jqxhr2 = $.getJSON("summers.json");
  return $.when(jqxhr1, jqxhr2);
}

gatherData().done(function(workshopData, summerData) {
  console.log("workshop data: ", workshopData);
  console.log("summer data: ", summerData);
  update(); // call update which can now access workshopData and summerData (if passed through)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are not yet ready for `Promise`s and `async/await`. You can stick with "callback hell" for now:

```
$.getJSON("workshops.json", function(data){
    workshopData = data;
    $.getJSON("summers.json", function(data){
        summerData = data;
        update();
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

When one request compiles it will call nested callback with the next request. And when it completes the second callback will call `update`